# I try to put a SQL-Command as a SQL-Parameter but it doesn't work cause of a converting error. C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parameters, ado.net

I have a problem with my code. I just started coding in C#. Let me explain.

My table I am working with has 3 columns.
ID(int), Column2(varchar50), Column3(bit).
I want to switch True or False from Column3 over a button in my C# Windows.Forms project.
My code already worked by switching it when i loaded the Table1 in the datagridview1 (cause i just had to put `Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[...].Value` as the value from the cmd.Parameters().Value) but now i want to make the action based on the selection of a view in my datagridview1. The view displays the Column2 from Table1 and another value from another table.

```cs
connection.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Table1 SET Column3 = CASE WHEN Table1.Column3 =
 'True' THEN 'False' WHEN Table1.Column3 = 'False' THEN 'True' ELSE Table1.Column3 END
 WHERE (ID = @Original_ID) AND (Column3 = @Original_Column3); SELECT ID, Column2, Column3 FROM Table1 WHERE (ID = @ID)";

cmd.Parameters.Add("Original_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = $"SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE Column2 = 
{Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value)}";
cmd.Parameters.Add("Original_ID", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = $"SELECT Column3 FROM Table1 WHERE Column2 = 
{Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value)}";
cmd.Parameters.Add("Original_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = $"SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE Column2 = 
{Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value)}";

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

The exception i am getting is "Parametervalue cant be converted from String in Int32".
I dont know if SQL Parameters can handle a string. I alredy tried converting everything but nothing works. I hope someone can solve my problem.

My code already worked by switching it when i loaded the Table1 in the datagridview1 (cause i just had to put `Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[...].Value` as the value from the cmd.Parameters().Value)

Comment: You are trying to set the parameter value to a SQL statement. It should be `cmd.Parameters.Add("Original_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value)"`

Comment: If you need to execute subqueries as part of your command then those subqueries need to be in the `CommandText`, not the parameters. Only the variable values you need to use in those subqueries goes in the parameter.

Comment: Parameters are equivalent to *function* parameters. Not variables or string placeholders.  The parameter values never become part of the query. The server compiles the query into a parameterized execution plan and runs that compiled plan using the parameter values. The question's code tries to pass a string containing `SELECT ....` to a parameter that only expects integer values, or at least strings that can be converted to integers

Comment: Thank you @jmcilhinney , you solved my Problem. I wrote it in the CommandText and now it works.